# What exactly iOS Crash report "Hardware Model" means?

Tags: iphone, ios, hardware, device, crash-reports

what does exactly

```
Hardware Model: iPhone1,2
```

means? I've got this report from an iPhone 3G device.

Now I have some reports with

```
Hardware Model: iPhone 3,1
```

What kind of device could it be exactly?
I have some

```
Hardware Model: iPod4,1
```

in addition, also have no guess.

Answer (score 11):

Here you are:

http://www.everyi.com/by-identifier/ipod-iphone-ipad-specs-by-model-identifier.html

> For your convenience, the Model Identifier (sometimes called Machine Model by "old school" Mac users) of each iPod, iPhone and iPad is listed below. Complete technical specifications are merely a click away.
>
> Note that the same Model Identifier may be used for multiple devices and was not used for devices that do not run iOS (formerly called iPhone OS or OS X). Nevertheless, this listing should be useful when trying to track down a particular iPod, iPhone or iPad...